# Have there been any changes to the UI of the Lync Client SDK controls?

Tags: wpf, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

My company embedded a Lync client into our client using the WPF controls provided by the Lync 2010 SDK.  Over the years we have gotten complaints that our embedded Lync client looks dated compared to the UI changes in Lync 2013 and Skype For Business 2015.

I took a look at the Lync 2013 SDK, and the example apps that use those controls appear to still have the same UI as the 2010 version.

While a new web SDK has been released for Skype for Business, it appears that there was no update to the desktop SDK since the 2013 release.

Is there a newer SDK that I should be looking at, or some sort of property or hint that I can set to get a different look to the UI?

A couple examples of the "dated" controls are Microsoft.Lync.Controls.ContactSearchInputBox and Microsoft.Lync.Controls.ContactSearchResultList

Comment: I haven't noticed any updates to the actual controls with the latest SDK but if the look is causing complaints then you could use the Lync Client API and WPF to create your own fresher ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lync/Skype for Business client SDK has been largely untouched since Lync 2010. (this is evidenced by user control look and features added in Lync 2013 and later have not made it into the SDK)

The latest I've heard from Microsoft (Nov 2015) the Lync SDK works with Skype for Business client (as is) but no updates are planned.